# What Bell states do apply to entangled electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electrons, quantum-entanglement

Electrons are fermions with spin $\pm \tfrac12$ obeying the Pauli exclusion principle. Is it then correct to conclude that only the wavefunctions of the two Bell states $|\Psi+\rangle$ and $|\Psi-\rangle$ (out of the four possible Bell states) can be applied to two entangled electrons?

Comment: What are the "four possible Bell states"?

Comment: Please see this Wiki link under "Bell Basis": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state

Comment: Thank you. ....

Comment: Suppose two particles are "entangled". Electron A and electron B will now show opposite spins when measured. Electron A is passed through an inhomogeneous magnetic field (Stern-Gerlach measurement). The result is that it is deflected UP. Therefore, entanglement says that when we pass electron B through  a similar inhomogeneous magnetic field, the result is DOWN with 100% probability. Further implications seem fuzzy because discussions are often abstract and general on what exactly happens to electron B after electron A is measured.

Comment: The remaining two Bell spin states are symmetric so, in principle,  it would be sufficient that the orbital part of the wave function be anti symmetric to agree with the fermionic statistics.

Comment: @ValterMoretti there has occurred a fundamental change in electron B after electron A is measured, hasn't there? Before A is measured, the spin states are the superposition of UP and DOWN states. After measurement of the other electron, the spin Bloch sphere representation states has changed to a pure DOWN arrow. Is there a testable statistical manifestation of this changed measurement probability of the electron?

Answer (score 2):

No, in principle also the states $\Phi$ are permitted. What the Pauli principle constraints is the anti symmetry of the global state of the two particles. Let us assume this state factorised as the product of an orbital part and a spin part.

The spin states $\Phi$ are symmetric so, in principle, it would be sufficient that the orbital part of the wave function be anti symmetric to agree with the Pauli principle.

Comment: Also, as you say "What the Pauli principle constraints is the anti-symmetry of the global state of both particles", so this can be applied to the fact that entangled particles are not spatially co-located.